# PHP / MySQLi - How to get value of one row and store in a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding, mysqli

I am going through my code and I am running so many queries it is getting long.  If I just want to store a single variable with a value, I have to do this:

```
switch($type) {
    case "next":
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sort_order FROM user_slides WHERE user_id = ? AND sort_order > ? ORDER BY sort_order LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $user_id, $sortId);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($next_sort_id);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();

        return $next_sort_id;

        $stmt->close();
    }
    break;

    case "first":
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT MIN(sort_order) as max_slides FROM user_slides WHERE user_id = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($first_sort_id);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();

        return $first_sort_id;

        $stmt->close();
    }
    break;

    case "last":
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT MAX(sort_order) as max_slides FROM user_slides WHERE user_id = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($last_sort_id);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();

        return $last_sort_id;

        $stmt->close();
    }
    break;
}
```

There has to be an easier way to do this.  Where I can just do it like this:

```
$first_sort_id = QUERY HERE
$last_sort_id = QUERY HERE
```

So it doesn't have to be so long, it can be nice and short.

Does anyone know what I need to do to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

If you use `return` the statement `$stmt->close();` will be never executed.

**Second**

Get rid of two vars, you just need one. Don't get fooled by semantic meanings.

**Third**

A simple reorganization could be this:

```
switch($type)
{
   case "next":
      $Query = "SELECT sort_order";
   break;
   case "first":
      $Query = "SELECT MIN(sort_order)";
   break;
   case "last":
      $Query = "SELECT MAX(sort_order)";
   break;
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("$Query as max_slides FROM user_slides WHERE user_id = ?"))
{
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($value);
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->fetch();
      $stmt->close();

      return $value;
}
else
   return NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for your help!  I edited my answer to include the whole switch statement.  see the "next" case has a different query than the other two, can I still make your answer work?

Comment: if you scroll to the right my next query is actually a lot longer than the other ones with different options.  and really, I might need this for a lot of other queries where I just need to return a single value.  is there a more universal solution which can apply to anything?

Comment: @Drew Well, in this case in every "case" you have to put the query, the prepare statement and the bind. The other instruction can go after the switch.

Comment: but for the next case, I am binding 2 variables $stmt->bind_param('is', $user_id, $sortId); and the other ones I am just binding one

Comment: @Drew and that's why I said "and the bind" in the last comment.